# Android app crashes on release build but works in debug build - React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, crash, release

i know this is a common problem but the error i am seeing is different here's the error

```
06-13 15:37:51.081  1690  3926 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.lawyr/.MainActivity bnds=[849,682][1056,960] (has extras)} from uid 10020 on display 0
06-13 15:37:51.137  1690  1782 I ActivityManager: Start proc 13071:com.lawyr/u0a88 for activity com.lawyr/.MainActivity
06-13 15:37:51.285 13071 13071 D SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.lawyr-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
06-13 15:37:51.290 13071 13071 D SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.lawyr/lib-main flags = 1]
06-13 15:37:51.293 13071 13071 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.lawyr-1/lib/x86 flags = 0]
06-13 15:37:51.294 13071 13071 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.lawyr/lib-main flags = 1]
06-13 15:37:51.297 13071 13071 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.lawyr/lib-main
06-13 15:37:51.299 13071 13071 I fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.lawyr/lib-main
06-13 15:37:51.299 13071 13071 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.lawyr/lib-main
06-13 15:37:51.337 13071 13071 E EmbeddedLoader:    at com.lawyr.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:86)
06-13 15:37:51.338 13071 13071 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.lawyr, PID: 13071
06-13 15:37:51.338 13071 13071 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.lawyr.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:86)
06-13 15:37:51.340  1690  2045 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.lawyr/.MainActivity
06-13 15:37:51.850  1690  1703 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{30dba1e u0 com.lawyr/.MainActivity t51 f}
06-13 15:37:51.853  1690  1703 I WindowManager: Failed to capture screenshot of Token{cc192ff ActivityRecord{30dba1e u0 com.lawyr/.MainActivity t51 f}} appWin=Window{ad21564 u0 Starting com.lawyr} drawState=4
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.lawyr;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "main";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```
package com.lawyr;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.lawyr.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList(),
    null
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    // initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
   *
   * @param context
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here's s my packages.json

```
{
  "name": "Lawyr",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "eslint": "^5.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.25.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest-expo": "^37.0.0",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.17",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
    "expo": "^37.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.2",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-hr-component": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-mock-render": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paystack": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "11.0.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.77",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.3",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

i did build release and the app crashes on launch i tried build it with debug and run without error.

the app was initially in expo but did `expo eject` to get the ios and android folders

Comment: Please include contents of `MainApplication.java`, `MainActivity` and the `package.json` (*to check RN version used*).

Comment: @ChristosLytras i have edited my question to include those files

Comment: Do you have `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` at the very top of your `index.js`? If you don't add it and try cleaning/re-building the release again.

Comment: Please don't use `expo eject` it doesn't at all work (it should be deprecated). You better create new project using `react-native-cli` and copy all required files from your expo managed project and slightly have to install different packages(also changing some imports). This really sounds as a lot of work but it isn't (Trust me - I have recently tried and failed doing expo eject so I setup a new react-native project and manually configured everything)

Comment: Are you using obfuscation in your release build and not in your debug build? Obfuscation may cause this problem if you are trying to auto-generate class objects from json or similar data based on a name inside your data and if your class' name has been changed when obfuscated.

Comment: @ChristosLytras your comment actually worked i added that line at the top of index.js and started working.

Comment: @Surafel yes, that's why I asked you to include your `package.json`, to see if you have packages such as `react-native-gesture-handler` that require special handling. I've added an answer if you care to accept but I've added it mostly for future readers having the same problem like you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently `react-native-gesture-handler` has to be imported before everything for the release build to work without crashing.

Add this line at the very top of `index.js`:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Then try to clean and rebuild the release again.

Comment: @TrịnhĐứcDuy it took me some hours to figure this out. Nasty bug that can drive people crazy!

Answer (score 5):

You should put **--minify=false** in **extraPackagerArgs** in **android/app/build.gradle**

as some of the classes/functions/methods might be ignored and not included in the release build if the compiler thinks its not used. In your case, the compiler might not have included expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController or the whole expo library.

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    extraPackagerArgs: [ '--minify=false' ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day, its really worked

Answer (score 1):

recently, I detected that JS engine in react native non-debug mode is different than the one in debug mode, because in debug mode, your code runs in chrome V8 engine but in none-debug mode, it runs in JavaScriptCore embedded in your devices. so some feature does not work well in non-debug mode like some of date function ,etc.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me hope it will save your hours
Note: if you are working on react native cli then remove it
else for expo leave as it is.

**package.json, remove this line "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",**

Comment: It's work for me... but what's happens, why is necessary to remove the expo entry point ?